# WordPress Multisite Wildcard domains

Tags: multisite

I have set up a wordpress multisite, https://cosandtogs.co.uk/

It has a wildcard in Cloudflare, the DNS are set up which might be right, the multisite works, but if i add a domain https://Banzaijapan.club it goes to and I have a 500 error, the first website works

Its been set up in Plesk

There is a wildcard in the domain alias, I have done this before many years ago i do not know why it wont work.

This is all i have done. I have not edited any files as I did not have to do this before and I dont know where or how

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
I do not know why its not working ive shown everything i have done

Comment: Have you configured Banzai Japan anywhere in WordPress? Is it going to be a separate site or just show the Cos site again?

Comment: its added in wordpress site    Edit Site: Banzaijapan.club
Site info updated.

Dismiss this notice.
Visit | Dashboard

Comment: [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwQnR.png

Comment: It would be better to [update your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/417149/edit) to include more information than to post it as comments. If nothing else, it'll keep all the relevant information in the question itself.

Comment: how im i meant to reply to a comment if not here and i do not understand this question Have you configured Banzai Japan anywhere in WordPress? Is it going to be a separate site or just show the Cos site again? what ? and if i try and and a break in my typing it just posts the comment, really bad website to use

Comment: Right, sorry, I though that was another Plesk screenshot. If you're getting 500 errors now then you can look in your server error logs to see what the error is specifically, although I'm not sure how that works with Plesk. If you find an error and stack trace please edit it into your question.

Comment: I am asking how do i set up wordpress multisite to run on plesk with domain names as i have obvisally not done it right

Comment: I now have a blabk page and the dashboard is for the main site